# Getting "Array to string conversion" error when trying to insert into MSSQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am receiving the above error when trying to insert into a SQL Server DB. The error is line 25, which is the `$logQuery` line but I am pretty sure that it has something to do with the insert statement, which is line 24. Here is the insert statement:

```
$logInsert = "INSERT into log (id, title, description, dateTime) VALUES ('', 'In', 'ADMIN: Todd Thelin logged into site.', GETDATE())";
```

And here is the query:

```
$logQuery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $logInsert) or die("Could not add to log: " . sqlsrv_errors());
```

How do I fix this error? I have tried multiple things but none of them are working. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe `sqlsrv_errors()` is returning an array. That makes the `die` function to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but it helped me realize the following solution for this... wrapping print_r() around the sqlsrv_errors() function:

```
$logQuery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $logInsert) or die("Could not add to log: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
```